# Describe a policy in AWS using the CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli

It might seems a silly question but I'm not able and I haven't find any command to show in the aws CLI the policy body. I have a managed policy attached to a role. I can simply display the ID and other information but not the body. Am I missing anything?

I run

`aws iam get-policy --policy-arn <arn>`

and get something like:

```
{
    "Policy": {
        "PolicyName": "developer_allow",
        "CreateDate": "2017-03-28T12:57:11Z",
        "AttachmentCount": 1,
        "IsAttachable": true,
        "PolicyId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "DefaultVersionId": "v1",
        "Path": "/",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:policy/developer_allow",
        "UpdateDate": "2017-03-28T12:57:11Z"
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. Not a stupid question at all! How confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was slightly more complicated but here the command:

`aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:policy/developer_allow --version-id v1`

You need to specify the version

Comment: In order to get it all in one command: `POLICY="arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:policy/developer_allow" ; aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn $POLICY --version-id $(aws iam get-policy --policy-arn $POLICY --query 'Policy.DefaultVersionId' --output text)`